# Returning two different rows in a new data type in PlPGSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to write a function that returns the data from two different rows, in a new data type.

This is what I have so far:

```
CREATE TABLE foo(
                   dt       DATE NOT NULL,
                   f1       REAL NOT NULL,
                   f2       REAL NOT NULL,
                   f3       REAL NOT NULL,
                   f4       REAL NOT NULL,
                );




CREATE TYPE start_finish_type AS (start_f1 REAL, start_f2 REAL, start_f3 REAL, start_f4 REAL,
                                finish_f1 REAL, finish_f2 REAL, finish_f3 REAL, finish_f4 REAL);


CREATE FUNCTION fetch_begin_end_data(start_date DATE, finish_date DATE)
RETURNS start_finish_type AS $$
DECLARE
actual_start_date  DATE;
actual_finish_date DATE ;
retval             start_finish_type;
BEGIN
    -- Select earliest row matching start_date
    SELECT MIN(dt) INTO actual_start_date  FROM foo WHERE dt >= start_date;
    SELECT MIN(dt) INTO actual_finish_date FROM foo WHERE dt <= finish_date;

    SELECT f1,f2, f3, f4 FROM foo WHERE dt = actual_start_date;
    SELECT f1,f2, f3, f4 FROM foo WHERE dt = actual_finish_date;

    -- How do I store the values obtained above and return them in the new type?

END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My question is: How do I modify the function so that it returns the data from the two different rows, and returns them in the new data type?

Comment: Consider using underscores to separate words in your function/type to make things more readable.

Comment: @eurotrash Point taken. Now for something completely off-topic, but can I just say, that I simply love your username ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION fetchbeginenddata(start_date DATE, end_date DATE)
RETURNS startfinishtype AS $$
DECLARE
actual_start_date  DATE;
actual_finish_date DATE ;
retval             startfinishtype;
BEGIN
    -- Select earliest row matching start_date
    SELECT MIN(dt) INTO actual_start_date  FROM foo WHERE dt >= start_date;
    SELECT MIN(dt) INTO actual_finish_date FROM foo WHERE dt <= finish_date;

    SELECT (a.f1,a.f2, a.f3, a.f4,b.f1,b.f2, b.f3, b.f4)
    FROM
      (SELECT f1,f2, f3, f4 FROM foo WHERE dt = actual_start_date) a
    JOIN
      (SELECT f1,f2, f3, f4 FROM foo WHERE dt = actual_finish_date) b
    ON true into retval;
   return retval;


END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

of course it requires that those two selects both return by one row

**update**
as @eurotrash states you might want to explicitly name composite type attributes to match order, like:

```
INTO retval.start_f1, retval.start_f2, ...
```

istead of just

```
INTO retval;
```

Comment: I would also specify the actual fields in retval, e.g. `INTO retval.start_f1, retval.start_f2, ...` otherwise any change to the type including field reordering would result in data in incorrect fields.